# No default constructor, When there is

Tags: c++, class

Why do I get the error "No default constructor exists for class "Sub", even though I have the constructor for Sub class"

```
    class Base{
    private:
        int x;      
    public:
        Base(int number) 
        {
            x = number;
        }
        virtual void print(void) = 0;       
    };
    
    
    class Sub: public Base{
    
    public:
        Sub(int x): Base(x) {       
        }
        void print() 
        {
           cout << "Testing" << endl;    
        }
        
    
    };
```

Comment: a default constructor is a constructor taking NO arguments.

Comment: You have not defined: `Sub::Sub()`

Comment: Add this to Sub:  `Sub() : Base{0} { }`

Comment: Wherever you're getting that error you're trying to initialize a `Sub` object without any arguments. You need to either fix that or add a default constructor.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to have a [mre].  The code you show here [does not produce](https://godbolt.org/z/v3sGEP1qP) the error you show here.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>A default constructor is one taking NO arguments.</strike> A default constructor is one which requires no provided arguments.

`Base()` and `Base(args = default)` are both considered default constructors, as no arguments are required. Please note the second one is **Pseudo Code**.

```
   class Base{
    private:
        int x;      
    public:
        Base(int number) 
        {
            x = number;
        }
        virtual void print(void) = 0;       
    };
    
    
    class Sub: public Base{
    
    public:
        Sub(int x): Base(x) {       
        }
        void print() 
        {
           cout << "Testing" << endl;    
        }
        
    
    };
```

Your code definitely does not have a default constructor.

Declaring a constructor automatically disables the compiler-created default contructor.

More info:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=only-default-constructors-c

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_constructors.asp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constructors-cpp

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/constructors/

Comment: I'd also mention that declaring a constructor disables the automatic definition of the default constructor.

Comment: Also note `your_class(int i = 0){}` is also considered a ***default constructor***, while taking arguments.